# Flutter add to app Android shows white screen on startActivity

Tags: flutter

I have an app where there are some screens that are made in Flutter (add2app). I have a class called CMFlutterActivity that is a subclass of `io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity`. I use this class to manage the method channels, but I am not too happy with how the screen is presented, because the first Flutter frame is not available when the Activity is presented. After some research I figured there is a method in the FlutterActivity that I can override to know when the first Flutter frame is available, it is called `onFlutterUiDisplayed`. The problem I have is: how do I manage to only make the Activity visible after this method has been called? Has anyone solved this problem already?

I am currently starting the activity in the following manner:

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent(context, CMFlutterActivity::class.java))
```

Here are some of my configurations:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".ui.flutter.CMFlutterActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoFullscreen"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    android:exported="true"
/>
```

styles.xml:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.NoFullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```